# What do you call this gray line thing in HTML

Tags: html, line

What do you call this "gray line" in HTML, where you can use like a separator?

Comment: @ALL: thanks for the reply. Yes that's what I mean;-) 
Thanks thanks ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`<hr />` is this what you mean?

Answer (score 6):

this is called a horizontal rule and can be created using the following:

```
<hr />
```

However, the fact that the line is gray is online its default behaviour. Using CSS you can style it as you like.

Comment: Except that so many problems arise with styling `<hr/>` elements in older browsers that it's best to use a `<div class="hr"></div>` and style `.hr` instead of `hr` to neatly sidestep the whole issue.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're talking about the [`<hr />`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp) element. HR stands for horizontal rule.

Comment: Isn't it a (H)orizontal(R)ule?

Comment: Last I checked, it stood for Horizontal Rule.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably referring to `<hr/>`, which is a *[Horizontal](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp) [Rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/graphics.html#h-15.3)*.

Answer (score 2):

`<hr />`, which is horizontal rule

It doesn't need to be gray either as it can take styles just like anything else, although how these behave in different browsers can be tricky.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean simply a nicely formatted `|` character?

Or perhaps a horizontal rule? `<hr />`

One thing I always found was CSS control over an HR tag is very limited, I always tend to go for a div defined in my CSS as being long and thin.

Answer (score 0):

you can customize the `<hr/>` by

```
    <hr style="margin: 0px 5em; border: 1px solid grey; border-radius: 1em; background-color: gray;">
```